# TFS Tree Query contains unexpected linked items

Tags: tfs

I created a TFS Query which works fine if runs as simple flat list query, there are no Terminated items as expected. Note that the brackets `[]` indicate the grouping.

```
Team Project    =   @Project
[ And   Work Item Type  =   Epic
Or  Work Item Type  =   Improvement ]
And State   <>  Terminated
[ And   Iteration Path  Under   A\B1
Or  Iteration Path  Under   A\B2 ]
```

Now I want to use this as a query for linked items within a tree query though. In this case I get linked work items in the state `Terminated` even though I explicitly exclude them in the query. Why is this?

I can imagine that this may be the case due to the children not being terminated, however I still would expect them to be filtered, because in a flat list they are filtered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Which filtered option you select in your query.  ***To find linked children, select Match top-level work items first. To find linked parents, select Match linked work items first.***

[image]

You can also achieve that result  by creating some custom code that uses the [tfs api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130306.aspx) to execute two queries (parent/children) and intersect their results.